# Are assert and NDEBUG being used a lot these days?

Tags: c++, debugging, c-preprocessor

I want to know whether the assert and NDEBUG parts are used in modern c++.

There are thread and memory checkers such as valgrind and sanitizer. And in unit testing, gtest is famous.
And even if I use those, I'm not sure why the debug part is taken out of the preprocessing separately. I think that the code that finds the bug always should be preserved.

Comment: assert failures terminate the program. If this is a mobile game, then that's probably fine. If it is a subroutine controlling fuel injection on an aircraft, it is probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first define the requirements not defined in your question:

> Are assert and NDEBUG being used **a lot** **these days**?

I assume "a lot" means over than one.

I assume that "these days" means this year.

> I want to know whether the assert and NDEBUG parts are used in **modern c++**.

I have no idea what is "modern c++". I assume "modern c++" is used by `boost/asio` library, used for this answer, as boost is a big, great, advanced library written in C++. And asynchronous is a hard topic, so I assume that the author of the library speaks "modern c++".

Let's download boost/asio sources and let's see if there were any usages of `assert` and `NDEBUG`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/boostorg/asio.git
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h" --since 2022-01-01 | xargs -n1 git show | grep assert
+    assert(completion);
     assert(impl_);
     assert(impl_);
+  static_assert(
+  static_assert(
-    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<allocator_type>);
-    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<allocator_type>);
-    assert(cancel);
       assert(ch && !ch.done());
-    void unhandled_exception() { assert(false); }
-      assert(executor);
-      assert(h);
-      assert(self_);
 #include <boost/asio/detail/assert.hpp>
+* Removed faulty assertions from `experimental::coro` implementation.
    Remove faulty assertions from experimental::coro implementation.
       assert(ch && !ch.done());
-      assert(coro->awaited_from == detail::noop_coroutine());
       assert(ch && !ch.done());
-      assert(coro->awaited_from == detail::noop_coroutine());
-        assert(coro->awaited_from == detail::noop_coroutine());
-        assert(coro->awaited_from == detail::noop_coroutine());
+  static_assert(asio::is_async_operation<decltype(d)>::value);
+  static_assert(
     assert(impl_);
      static_assert(asio::is_async_operation<decltype(d)>::value);
      static_assert(
+  static_assert(
-  static_assert(
+  assert(!ok);
-  [[expression] [return type] [assertion/note[br]pre/post-conditions]]
+#include <cassert>
+          assert(length < data_.size());
diff --git a/include/boost/asio/detail/assert.hpp b/include/boost/asio/detail/assert.hpp
--- a/include/boost/asio/detail/assert.hpp
+++ b/include/boost/asio/detail/assert.hpp
 // detail/assert.hpp
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h" --since 2022-01-01 | xargs -n1 git show | grep NDEBUG
```

This line `+    assert(completion);` shows that `assert` is beeing used "a lot" "these days" in "modern c++".

However, `NDEBUG` was not beeing used "a lot" "these days" in this "modern c++" project. Most probably it is used by other projects. This answer aims to give you the tools that should allow you to check if something is used or not depending on the constraints you want to restrict your search with.